# Error when in signalR ASP.NET when trying to connect to SQL server in Azure

Tags: sql, asp.net, azure, signalr

I am trying to connect signalR to an SQL server in azure.

[PlatformNotSupportedException: The SQL Server edition of the target server is unsupported, e.g. SQL Azure.]

After follow the instructions on Microsoft Documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-sql-server

Service Broker is enabled.

Comment: We needed  the Azure SignalR Service in azure.us but it's not available there yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form MSDN article:

Prerequisites

*Microsoft SQL Server 2005 or later. The backplane supports both desktop and server editions of SQL Server. It does not support SQL Server Compact Edition or **Azure SQL Database**. (If your application is hosted on Azure, consider the Service Bus backplane instead.)*

If your application will be hosted in Azure and you're using ASP.NET Core, you should consider the use of the Azure SignalR Service as an alternative which offers first class integration with Azure Services including SQL Azure.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-signalr-service-a-fully-managed-service-to-add-real-time-functionality/

Here's a quickstart:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-dotnet-core